# Is the computer the role runs on the same?

Tags: wcf, azure, self-hosting

I have a self hosted wcf service with a startup task that runs

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:{PORT}/{SERVICENAME} user=everyone listen=yes delegate=yes"
```

previously the service didn't have ssl, but the old http url reservation was still there (or was added by something else I'm not aware of).

So do I need to add a netsh remove to startup task?

EDIT: 
I remove desktop-ed to the role to check if the reservation is there.

Comment: you can never assume it will be the same, it often is, but if there were a hardware failure and your role were restarted within the data center elsewhere, it certainly wouldn't be. Any startup task would need to be idempotent.

Comment: @JimO'Neil can you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never assume it will be the same, it often is, but if there were a hardware failure and your role were restarted within the data center elsewhere, it certainly wouldn't be. Any startup task would need to be idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

To make you understand better the scenario, when you deploy your application in cloud, you are running application in a virtual machine within virtualize environment. Your application will be running within a data center however the virtual machine will be hosted on a host machine which can be changed any time due to any particular reason. This is possible due to Guest OS or Host OS update, hardware failure, resources change requirement, and any other reason. Because of it you should not consider that your virtual machine will always be same, to be more specific it is "virtual".